# Difference between Bash shell on Windows and Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Apart from the app Ubuntu on my Windows 10, I noticed if I search for 'bash', I also find a `bash.exe` installed in my computer. The Bash shell felt slightly faster to use than the Ubuntu app. Was this just circumstantial, or is there really a difference between these two?

Comment: Do you have git installed perhaps? You could be using the shell that comes with git or something.   You really don't get much with it.

Comment: I go have Git installed and Git Bash did show up before this ```bash.exe```. However, at least the colors and usernames in Git Bash and ```bash.exe``` are different, and the ```bash.exe``` ones looking exactly like on Ubuntu WSL. Also, what cannot I get from from the Git Bash? I will try that on ```bash.exe```.